# Python property best practices

Tags: python

Is there any situation where it makes sense to define a python property, where getting (not setting) it would raise an exception? I don't think this ever happens for fields in classes, hence the question.

Or is always better in these cases to use a method instead?

Comment: What kind of exceptions? Certainly there are good reasons a property might raise `NotImplementedError`, `AttributeError`, etc.

Comment: Lets say ones used more often in methods, `KeyError`, `ValueError`.

Comment: @simonzack: What makes you think `KeyError` and `ValueError` are used more often in methods?

Comment: recommended reading: **[Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)**

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not sure but take them as examples not used by accessing fields.

Comment: @gnat Where would I ask the question then? I wanted to ask this on StackOverflow, but a meta post directed me here.

Comment: what meta post are you talking about? meanwhile, consider checking [this meta post](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490)

Comment: @gnat Forgot which post, but I'm not sure where or how to ask a question like this then, imho this really isn't that different to a design pattern question.

Comment: @simonzack: There are different ways of wording a design pattern question. The term 'best practice' is like a red flag to a bull; your question is too much devoid of detail to avert said bull.

Answer (score 2):

I've created properties that raise exceptions in situations where I didn't want `__init__` to raise exceptions and/or I wanted to delay processing.

```
class Identifier:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def prefix(self):
        # ...
        # parse prefix from self._value
        # raise ValueError is provided value cannot be parsed
        # ...
        return prefix

    @property
    def suffix(self):
        # ...
        # parse suffix from self._value
        # raise ValueError is provided value cannot be parsed
        # ...
        return suffix
```